# Image subfolders in HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script

Tags: html, compression, boilerplate

I'm trying to get the HTML5 Boilerplate build script to minify my img folder. It works fine but it will only compress images within the parent folder.

For example If I had

- **img folder**

  - img1
  - img2
  - **subfolder**

    - img3
    - img4
  - **subfolder2**

    - img5
    - img6

Only img1 and img2 will be compressed.

I realise I can specify a subfolder path, but what I want is for the build script to run through all subfolders.

I've tried modifying the dir.images of the default.properties with img/* and img* but that flags up errors.